# Selenium WebDriver and loaded images

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium webdriver for automated tests. I developed a test which navigates to some page with many images. I want to save data of images which was downloaded by webbrowser. I can only call same url adress, but there is problem because images are dynamicaly generated. The target is save data of images which was showed in the web page without another http request.

Could you help me or give me any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please eloberate what do you mean by saving data of images ? Also sample HTML code snippet of your page would help.

Comment: do you want to save images showing on that web page?

Comment: Yes, I want to save images showing on page without another http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider creating a custom proxy that sits between Selenium and the remote servers.  This way you can intercept any content you like and save it off to disk.

Which bindings are you using?  For java, setting a proxy is pretty straight-forward - http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy

Desperate Options:

- The second least painful way is to snapshot the whole page with Selenium.  Once you have that, you could crop out the images you care for.  Pretty fragile and very hacky.
- You could also attack the page with JavaScript.  AFAIK, it's not possible for JS to scrape image bits.  So instead, you'd have to AJAX in the img urls and then set the IMG contents manually.  But that's really just an extremely awkward way to build a proxy.